Does a named standard exist for comment annotations?
I have encountered, and used, several different forms of comment annotations. Eg.
// TODO: Also trigger this task
// FIXME: in this very specific circumstance this should handle this way instead
// NOTE: This is important for this specific case

Do any named conventions or standards exist in regards to this?
I've seen different approaches with variations including:

The exact annotation names that are permissible (eg. sometime people use "PERF", "HACK", "WARN", etc.)
The format of these (FIXME: [message], fixme - [message]
Including task IDs (and how these should be denoted)

From my experience, it has come down very much to a standard of precedence within a team:

We've always used these annotations in this format, so that's how you should too

This is a good start - a standard is better than no standard. However, its a very opinionated standard and unclear in the accepted implementation. I was wondering whether there were any named conventions and guidelines one could reference to assist in the onboarding of new team members, and the automated linting of code?
NOTE: I appreciate that there is some level of controversy regarding whether these types of comments should/should not be used, however that is not within the scope of this question.
